# Lint error while running dockerized project on Github Actions

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, lint, flake8

This is the error that I'm getting while running my GH Actions:

```bash
Test and Lint

- Setup job - Done
- Checkout - Done
- Test - Done
- Lint
    Run docker-compose run —rm app sh -c “flake8”
    Creating recipe_app_api_app_run …
    Creating recipe_app_api_app_run … done
    ./core/management/commands/wait_for_db.py:5:57: W291 trailing whitespace
    ./core/management/commands/wait_for_db.py:23:73 W292 no newline end of file
    ./core/management/commands/wait_for_db.py:28:1 W391 blank line at end of file
    1
    Error: Process completed with exit code 1
```

Here is my setup for github actions:

```yaml
---
name: Checks

on: [push]

jobs:
  test-lint:
    name: Test and Lint
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Test
        run: docker-compose run --rm app sh -c "python manage.py wait_for_db && python manage.py test"
      - name: Lint
        run: docker-compose run --rm app sh -c "flake8"
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue that you are facing is that you have some extra spaces in the file `wait_for_db.py` specifically in lines `5` and also you need to add an empty line at the and of this file `23`. Also you have to make sure you only have one line the end of the `test_commands.py`.

Errors:

- W291: https://www.flake8rules.com/rules/W291.html
- W292: https://www.flake8rules.com/rules/W292.html
- W391: https://www.flake8rules.com/rules/W391.html

You can get a clear explanation of each `flake8` rule in the following link: https://www.flake8rules.com/

Comment: 1
Error: Process completed with exit code 1. what about this?

Comment: Yes `EXIT_CODE=1` means error. https://github.com/PyCQA/flake8/blob/14c5edf3365b70b5c3c054453d66d0c73cee5c3a/src/flake8/main/application.py#L58 in bash `EXIT_CODE=0` means success normally.